# what is the use of * in print(*a) where 'a' is a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing

I am a python newbie. I saw a code which had * inside a print function // print(*a) // in which 'a' was a list. I know * is multiplication operator in python, but don't know what's  it in a list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If you don't know about the variable number of argument methods, leave this topic and learn this after that)

**Unpacking elements in list**

Consider new_list = [1, 2, 3]. Now assume you have a function called *addNum(*arguments)* that expects 'n' number of arguments at different instances.

case 1:
Consider calling our function with one parameter in the list. How will you call it? Will you do it by *addNum(new_list[0])*?

Cool! No problem.

case 2: Now consider calling our function with two parameters in the list. How will you call it? Will you do it by *addNum(new_list[0], new_list[1])*?

Seems tricky!!

Case 3: Now consider calling our function with all three parameters in the list. Will you call it by *addNum(new_list[0], new_list[1], new_list[2])*? Instead what if you can split the values like this with an operator?

Yes! *addNum(new_list[0], new_list[1], new_list[2])* <=> *addNum(*new_list)*

Similarly, *addNum(new_list[0], new_list[1])* <=> *addNum(*new_list[:2])*

Also, *addNum(new_list[0])* <=> *addNum(*new_list[:1])*

By using this operator, you could achieve this!!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation about the Variable number of argument methods.

Answer (score 1):

It'd print all items without the need of looping over the list. The * operator used here unpacks all items from the list.

```
a = [1,2,3]

print(a) 
# [1,2,3] 

print(*a) 
# 1 2 3

print(*a,sep=",")
# 1,2,3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it